# How to turn off XML documentation in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How do I turn off XML documentation in Visual Studio so the XML documentation comments are not automatically added every time I create a new project/file?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
```

Answer (score 3):

To stop VS from producing the XML document files; right-click Properties on your project file and select the `Build` tab.  Under the `Output` div uncheck `XML documentation file:`

Comment: I dont want xml comments automatically in the source code files automatically each time I create a class etc..

Answer (score 1):

To do this you will need to edit the templates for Visual Studio 2008 (which are stored in ZIP files), and then update the cache.

The templates are located in

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates

Copy the zip file to edit to a working folder. 
Unzip the files, edit the template files, and rezip them back into a zip file.
Copy it back to the corresponding template folder.

Once you have edited the template file(s), open up the Visual Studio Command Prompt (you will probably need to run-as administrator) and type in:

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

This will update the cached template folders. (Do not yield to the temptation to edit the cached template files themselves. Your edits will get overwritten and lost next time the cache is refreshed).

For more details, refer to:

- http://ericsowell.com/blog/2007/5/22/how-to-edit-visual-studio-templates
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx